# MySQL SQL syntax query

Tags: java, mysql, sql

What SQL syntax do I need to count same values from different columns and rows?

Comment: There is no such thing as 'Java NetBeans syntax'. Almost certainly what you are really asking about is **SQL** syntax. Your time management issues are yours alone.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. Can you help me with the syntax of MysQL ?

Comment: could you post a sample data and your expected output..

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT operator in MySQL

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) AS 'Count' FROM table_name;
```